# 13.75V (AC) Door bell ringing signal to Raspberry Pi GPIO - Am I on the right track of which components I need? (Beginner)

Tags: microcontroller, resistors, raspberry-pi, opto-isolator, zener

I'm in the making of a RaspberryPi doorbell. It will have to possibility to send events and receive actions/commands via a Telegram bot (already working). The approach is to connect it to the handheld intercom (Siedle HT 611-01) in my apartment. It will be able to open the door, record, send and receive voice messages and initiate direct phone calls.

The project is nearly done and I just need some confirmation if I'm on the right track in terms of electronics, as this is my first project with an environment like this.

To receive the 13.75V (AC) door bell signal, I would use a Z-diode which "breaks" at some voltage level and forward the remaining voltage to a photocoupler - which then on the other hand is connected to the GPIO pin of the Raspberry Pi.

When the door bell button is pressed, I measured the following:
13.75V
130mA

The Raspberry Pi needs 3.3V on the GPIO IN and max 0.5mA, as far as I researched.

Which Z-diode, photocoupler and resistors would you recommend?

Thank you in advance. Any help is very much appreaciated!

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need a zener diode. Just a current limiting resistor to an opto-coupler's LED (with a parallel diode to handle reverse voltage), and its output to a pull-up on the Raspberry PI. You'll get a series of logic transitions while the signal is present.

Try using the editor/simulator to draw a schematic in your question.

Answer (score 0):

The 'NO' contact of a 12 V ~ relay may be used to pull down a GPIO input that has been held high with a pull-up resistor.

[image]